# How to anticipate bad solutions to system of equations?

Tags: regression, matrix-inverse

I know the identity that matrix $\mathbf{Y}$ is a product of $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{B}$ (all of which are integer matrices in my case):

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{X} \mathbf{B}
\end{equation}

With knowledge of $\mathbf{Y}$, $\mathbf{X}$, $\mathbf{B}$, I would like to find a matrix $\mathbf{P}$ from which I can obtain $\mathbf{X}$ from $\mathbf{Y}$:

\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{X}
\end{equation}

I compute $\mathbf{P}$ in one of two ways: 1) calculate the pseudoinverse $\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{B}^+$ and 2) solve $\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{P}=\mathbf{X}$ for $\mathbf{P}$.

My questions:

1. Under what conditions does the pseudo-inverse fail?
2. Under what conditions does the "solve" method fail?

By "fail," I mean that $\mathbf{P}$ does not provide an accurate reconstruction of $\mathbf{X}$.

Is it related to the extent of overfitting? I would like to know if I can anticipate failures from knowledge of the matrix properties. There is [this post](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/01/19/dont-invert-that-matrix/)  suggesting the "solve" method is always better for numerical reasons. However, my main objective is interpreting the elements of $\mathbf{P}$ and not speed. Conceptually, the pseudo-inverse only depends on knowledge of $\mathbf{B}$ -- and therefore the elements of $\mathbf{P}$ would have fixed interpretations for many such $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$ -- so for this reason it is desirable for my problem.

I provide two examples in R below.

**Example 1.** Pseudo-inverse fails but solve works

$\mathbf{X}$ is 3$\times$3 and $\mathbf{B}$ is 3$\times$2. Consequently, $\mathbf{Y}$ is 3$\times$2.

```
X <- rbind(c(1, 0, 1),
           c(1, 1, 1),
           c(1, 2, 1))
B <- rbind(c(3, 0),
           c(2, 0),
           c(2, 1))
Y <- X %*% B
P.inv <- MASS::ginv(B)
P.solve <- limSolve::Solve(Y, X)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
matplot(X, Y %*% P.inv, xlim=range(X), ylim=range(X))
abline(0, 1)
matplot(X, Y %*% P.solve, xlim=range(X), ylim=range(X))
abline(0, 1)
```

The following figure shows the reconstruction of $\mathbf{X}$ from $\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{P}$ by the pseudo-inverse method (left) and "solve" method (right).

[image: pseudo-inverse fail]

**Example 2.** Pseudo-inverse and solve both fail

$\mathbf{X}$ is 5$\times$5 and $\mathbf{B}$ is 5$\times$2. Consequently, $\mathbf{Y}$ is 5$\times$2.

```
X <- rbind(c(2, 2, 0, 0, 0),
           c(1, 2, 1, 0, 0),
           c(2, 1, 0, 1, 0),
           c(2, 1, 1, 0, 0),
           c(3, 0, 0, 0, 1))
B <- rbind(c(3, 0),
           c(2, 0),
           c(2, 1),
           c(1, 1),
           c(0, 1))
Y <- X %*% B
P.inv <- MASS::ginv(B)
P.solve <- limSolve::Solve(Y, X)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
matplot(X, Y %*% P.inv, xlim=range(X), ylim=range(X))
abline(0, 1)
matplot(X, Y %*% P.solve, xlim=range(X), ylim=range(X))
abline(0, 1)
```

The following figure shows the reconstruction of $\mathbf{X}$ from $\mathbf{Y}\mathbf{P}$ by the pseudo-inverse method (left) and "solve" method (right).

[image: solve method fail]

Comment: The pseudoinverse always exists. However, solving your system with pseudoinverses is not recommended: they are slow and numerically unstable. Instead, opt to use a plethora of other algorithms, such as QR or Cholesky. See here for the least-squares case: http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Lee.pdf

Comment: My apologies. I didn't mean in the sense that the solution does not exist, but that it does not provide a good reconstruction of $\mathbf{X}$ from $\mathbf{Y}$. Is it then the numerical instability which cases the difference in solution between the pseudoinverse and `solve`? Speed is not an issue for me in this case as the primary objective is to interpret elements of the matrix. I just edited my question to clarify these points.